# Any option for Physical GPU in VM without Vt-d?

Tags: vmware-esxi

i currently got a Server with Vt-x but no Vt-d.
I have a Nvidia Graphic card in server, but cant passtrough it with esxi because i need vt-d.
Is there any virtualsation which supports pci passtrough or use physical gpu performance on vm without Vt-d? Like citrix or proxmox kvm?
I know windows server is working, but i dont want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate, the only thing you can pass through without VT-d is storage, no matter the hypervisor.